# image handling(downloading/display) in django using html form

Tags: python, html, django, forms

i want to do some image processing using Django and now work and on the image handling(downloading/display) using Django.
first on my task i don't want to store that images on my server.
but i have some problems.

**UPDATE**

that my code:

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
#url(r'^$',views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^$',views.calc, name='calc'),
]
```

file.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>

</head>

<body>
<p>EXample form</p>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="num" id="num" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<p>
{{ num.url }}
{{ output1.url }}
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

def calc(request):
    num = request.POST.get('num', False)
    if request.method=='POST' and 'submit' in request.POST:
        '''
         do some image processing
         and finaly i take that outputs images
       '''
        output1 = "output1.tif"
        output2 = "output2.tif"
        output3 = "output3.tif"
    return render_to_response ('blog/calc.html', {'num':num,'output1':output1},RequestContext(request))
```

i don't take speficec error but if i choose image and i put submit then show error in my browser.

Comment: do you want to upload image and it should store right ?

Comment: i dont want store i want just take that image and response the new image

Comment: it would be really useful to see *what* error does it show (with `settings.DEBUG` set to `True`)

Comment: i thing so the error is because in the `<form action="" ` is none but how to fix that ? ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED in the browser